# ¿como sumar, restar fechas/horas u otras operaciones usando moments js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

espero que esten bien.

necesito sacar el lapso de una fecha a otra.

ejemplo:  8:58:00 AM - 7:46:00 AM = 01:12:00.

ejemplo2: 8:58:00 AM + 7:46:00 AM = 04:44:00 PM

basicamente necesito, sacar diferentes operaciones de una fecha a otra, en este caso estoy usando horas en formato 12hr, pero tambien tengo otros campos donde uso una fecha completa (dia/mes/año hr/mm/ss p), no sé que tipo de operaciones puedo hacer usando moment js, les agradeceria algunos ejemplos, gracias.

Comment: El Objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) de Javascript almacena un valor numérico que representa milisegundos desde un punto específico en el tiempo. Sumar y restar números no necesita de ninguna librería. Por otro lado, ¿en qué parte del mundo esto: ***8:58:00 AM + 7:46:00 AM = 04:44:00 PM*** tiene algún sentido?

Answer (score 2):

En el API de moment.js, encontrarás el método [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) para encontrar la diferencia entre dos momentos.
Por otro lado no puedes sumar fechas, pero a una fecha puedes sumarle unidades de tiempo con `add`, y restar con `subtract`:

```js
const ayer = moment('2020-09-02 14:00:00.000');
const hoy = moment('2020-09-03 08:40:00.000');

console.log(hoy.diff(ayer,'hours'));
console.log(hoy.diff(ayer,'minutes'));

console.log(hoy);
console.log(hoy.add(7, 'hours').subtract(1, 'seconds'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-rmZcZsyhe0/MAjquhTgiUcb4d9knaFc7b5xAfju483gbEXTkeJRUMIPk6s3ySZMYUHEcjKbjLjyddGWMrNEvZg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: obtengo este errorUncaught TypeError: hr2.diff is not a function. pero yo tengo la libreria de moment agregada a mi proyecto. https://momentjs.com/

Comment: ¿Qué es hr2? Si no muestras nada de código no te puedo ayudar

Comment: hr2 es la varibale  que almacena una fecha, es decir tus variables se llaman ayer y hoy y las mia hr1, hr2

Comment: ¿Y le has asignado un valor usando moment(...)? Porque si no es así es normal que no tengan el método diff

Answer (score 0):

Moment tiene un método llamado `diff`

```
var date1 = moment('2016-10-08 10:29:23');
var date2 = moment('2016-10-08 11:06:55');
var diff = date2.diff(date1);
```

Por lo que he visto no funciona si solo le pasas horas. Y de hecho hay un warning de que el formato debe ser ISO. Si siempre restas horas de un mismo día no es un gran problema porque puedes poner un día arbitrario

Comment: voy a probarlo, el caso es que hay unos campos que solo necesita almacenar una hora, por ende solo necesito hacer la operacion con horas en formato 12hr, si tengo otros que me serviria ya que si tiene fecha y hora.

Comment: En los campos que no tienes la fecha puedes añadir una fecha arbitraria ya que no debería afectar a la operación. para tu primer ejemplo:

8:58:00 AM - 7:46:00 AM
moment('1990-01-01 8:58:00').diff(moment('1990-01-01 7:46:00'))